# Is it a bad security to trust 127.0.0.1 (localhost) in ssh connections?

Tags: networking, ssh, security, port-forwarding

I have a script that permits me to forward SSH connections from a port on my machine to a remote host, accessing another remote host that is only accessible from this host:

```bsh
ssh -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -f -N -L <forward_port>:<database_url>:22 <user>@<remote_host_id> -i  <private_key>;
ssh -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" <user>@127.0.0.1 -p <forward_port>;
```

I use this script with multiple remote hosts/databases, and I want to always use the same `forward_port`, so I added options `-o "StrictHostKeyChecking no"` and `-o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"`; without these, this message appears:`IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!`

Is this secure? I think this basically means trusting `127.0.0.1` which most likely won't be spoofed.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.shellhacks.com/disable-ssh-host-key-checking/) answer your question?

Comment: It looks like what you're trying to do is use a jump host. There are [several](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts) natively-supported ways you can do this without forwarding a specific port (and without disabling host key checking).

Comment: Thanks @Bob this is way better than the way I was doing it! This makes it much more easier and secure and no need to worry about the issue I talked about!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually one could rephrase your question and ask: is it possible to mount this scenario into an attack which would not be possible if you would not disable host key checks.

The immediate idea is that an attacker re-routes the tunnel end to somewhere else and makes use of the fact that you execute the key based authentication there. Because this is the only thing your client would not notice - since the received host key is not validated.

But if we assume that you use the given private key only for those servers, an attacker cannot gain anything from re-routing the tunnel end to somewhere else - since the key is never accepted there. Ok, at worst he will make you authenticate at another server from your list than the one you expect, but in this case you would anyway bring him to the server you initially requested, and this looks not too different - I mean you have to evaluate this, but it seems a minor difference.

So from what I see so far, I would say the risk comprised with turning it off is acceptable.

[But please remember to use that key for nothing else!]

Answer (score 0):

Although I marked @fratester's answer as accepted(cause it is the right answer to the question), I could have done this ssh tunneling thing in a native way that is much easier and secure and without worrying about the security issue I was worried about.

As @Bob commented check this link https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts .